# How to use string processing with environment variable value in WinSCP command?

Tags: scripting, command, environment-variables, winscp

I want to manage (Upload\Download\Delete) a file on an FTP Server with WinSCP command line.

It says I can use environment variables! I have some text files that have the date in their name.

I just created the variable I want:

```
Test_%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%.txt
```

and tested it with Windows `echo` command. It becomes `Test_20140916.txt` and that is exactly what I have now.

But when I try to upload that file in WinSCP, I get this error:

```
winscp> put D:\FTP\Test_%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%.txt

File or folder 'D:\FTP\Test_%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%.txt' does not exist.
System Error.  Code: 123.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
(A)bort, (R)etry, (S)kip, Ski(p) all:
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinSCP supports a [timestamp formatting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp) natively:

```
put D:\FTP\Test_%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%
```

---

To explain why your syntax does not work: while WinSCP supports the environment variables in scripting commands, it does support only a basic syntax `%NAME%`, as documented:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#syntax

To achieve, what you need, you have to resolve the value to another variable and refer to that in the WinSCP command:

```
set STAMP=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%
winscp.com /script=script.txt
```

where `script.txt` can use `%STAMP%`:

```
put D:\FTP\Test_%STAMP%
```

Also note that a value of the `%DATE%` is locale-specific, so make sure you test your code on the same locale on which you gonna use it. Or even better, use a locale independent `wmic os get LocalDateTime`:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set LDT=%%j
set STAMP=%LDT:~0,4%%LDT:~4,2%%LDT:~6,2%
```